# Upload Pandas df in to Google sheets through API

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets

Some how all work correctly but when i trying upload new df to a new 'sheet' i get an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g

# Specify path to your file with credentials

path_to_credential = 'путь.json'

# Specify name of table in google sheets

table_name = 'py-to-google'


scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(path_to_credential, scope)

gs = gspread.authorize(credentials)
work_sheet = gs.open(table_name)

# Select 1st sheet
sheet1 = work_sheet.sheet1

# Get data in python lists format
data = sheet1.get_all_values()

# Get header from data
headers = data.pop(0)

# Create df
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)

spreadsheet_name = 'py-to-google'

sheet = 'py-to-google'


d2g.upload(df, spreadsheet_name, sheet, credentials=credentials, row_names=True)
```

```
/var/folders/wv/j__1xb_j3bjctrgyln3pnt7m0000gn/T/ipykernel_5022/1142499611.py:3: DeprecationWarning: [Deprecated][in version 6.0.0]: client_factory will be replaced by gspread.http_client types
  d2g.upload(df, spreadsheet_name, sheet, credentials=credentials, row_names=True)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/df2gspread/df2gspread.py:138: FutureWarning: DataFrame.applymap has been deprecated. Use DataFrame.map instead.
  df = df.applymap(str)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/df2gspread/df2gspread.py:138: FutureWarning: DataFrame.applymap has been deprecated. Use DataFrame.map instead.
  df = df.applymap(str)

<Worksheet 'py-to-google' id:2069214263>
```

I understand that is could be a small mistake from my side and this just make me crazy because i tired to search the issue! please some one look at this

Comment: I don't see `error` but only `warnings`. It is only information that some function will be removed in the future - and at this moment all works correctly but in the future it may not work. SO at this moment you don't have to worry. Frankly, problem is inside modules, not directly in your code, and you can't change it - you may have to wait for newer versions. At this moment use current version and don't bother this.

Comment: yea you right but why this script dont do anything? =)

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: wow nice idea brother for the first time i hear about "print debuging" thanks for idea! i actually know only classic debuging in VScode or JupyterLab or Thony.

Comment: `print debuging` can be tiring because you have to add many `print()` and later you have to remove it - but it works with any language without using external tools (debugers). SO when you start learning new language then you already know how to debug it using `print()` or similar function in new language. BTW: you may also use thes `prints` with extra variable `DEBUG = True` and later `if DEBUG: print(...)` and this way you may test it always when you find new problem. And later you can set `DEBUG = False` to run it without extra messages.

Comment: its sounds so easy but its better to see it once in video more than to read about this technique =) but thanks for advice brother.

Comment: in my case i dont know how it supposed find the bug because all my code works correctly except the last line with  '''d2g.upload()''' so i dont know how to "print debug" this peace =)

Answer (score 0):

*According to https://github.com/maybelinot/df2gspread/issues/61#issuecomment-1154522447 , df2gspread is [not actively maintained](https://github.com/maybelinot/df2gspread/issues) and you might want to use `gspread` directly (an example is provided in the comment linked above) or switch to a [gspread-dataframe](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe).*

That said, the output indicates that upload was successful and `<Worksheet 'py-to-google' id:2069214263>` is an object representing the gspread worksheet, to which the data has been uploaded. Perhaps it's not the worksheet you expected to be updated? Check its `.url` to be sure.

The other messages are harmless warnings:

- `DeprecationWarning: [Deprecated][in version 6.0.0]: client_factory will be replaced by gspread.http_client types` was a bug in gspread 5.12.0 (already [fixed](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/pull/1349))
- `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/df2gspread/df2gspread.py:138: FutureWarning: DataFrame.applymap has been deprecated. Use DataFrame.map instead.` is a heads-up that df2gspread will need to switch to the newer API to remain compatible with newer pandas versions.